# How do I cache user specific objects

Tags: ruby

I would like to cache the "foo" object for a specific key/secret combination. How should I go about doing this in ruby.

```
require 'foo/api'

foo = Foo::API::Client.new(key, secret)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you use for caching, and which kind of cache you want. Regardless the type of cache, the common procedure is to use key/secret as part of the cache key.

For instance, using memoization.

```
cache = {}
cache["foo-#{key}:{secret}"] ||= Foo::API::Client.new(key, secret)
```

You can wrap all in a class or method.

```
def client(key, secret)
  @clients ||= {}
  @clients["client-#{key}:{secret}"] ||= Foo::API::Client.new(key, secret)
end
```

If you want an external cache, such as file cache or memcached cache, simply adopt the same technique and compose the cache key using key and secret.

If key and secret are "secret" strings, you can compute a SHA or MD5 hash and use that as key, rather than the clear values.